# Terraform combine lookup and splat syntax

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to provision multiple Azure virtual machines with Terraform and then get the MSI identity ID for entitlements.  I started with this MSI example (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/authenticating_via_msi.html) that works for me and am trying to add count, i.e.

```html
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" {
  count = "5"
  name                  = "test"
  ....

  identity = {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  .....
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "virtual_machine_extension" {
  count = "5"
  name                 = "test"
  location             = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "test"
  virtual_machine_name = "${element(azurerm_virtual_machine.virtual_machine.*.name, count.index)}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity"
  type                 = "ManagedIdentityExtensionForWindows"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "port": 50342
    }
SETTINGS
}


output "vm_principals" {
  # original had --- "${lookup(azurerm_virtual_machine.virtual_machine.identity[0], "principal_id"}"
  value = ["${azurerm_virtual_machine.virtual_machine.*.identity[0]}"]
}
```

Problem is that I get an output array as following:

```html
vm_principals = [
  { 
     principal_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
     type = SystemAssigned
  }, 
  { 
     principal_id = yyyyyyyyyyyyy,
     type = SystemAssigned
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to get is

```html
vm_principals = [
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
]
```

I tried the obvious variations, but I suspect this is a Terraform limitation.

```html
  value = ["${lookup(azurerm_virtual_machine.virtual_machine.*.identity[0], "principal_id)}"]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're right. I believe you're hitting [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17048). However, this will probably be solved in v0.12 of Terraform as it will introduce a revamped language (HCL). See this [Hashicorp blog article](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-generalized-splat-operator) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I dealt with this issue

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "kubenode" {
  count = "3"
  ...
}
```

For a azurerm_virtual_machine resource named kubenode, you can do this:

```
${azurerm_virtual_machine.kubenode.*.identity.0.principal_id}
```

Which will return a list of principal ids. you can then do:

```
${azurerm_virtual_machine.kubenode.*.identity.0.principal_id[count.index]}
```

For example in a role-assignment scenario:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "kubenode-subscription-reader-role" {
  count                = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.kubenode.count}"
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.kubenode.*.identity.0.principal_id[count.index]}"
}
```